# Posting picture in a facebook group in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this facebook api version: Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.0.0)
This is my code:

```
params = array(
                'message'       =>  "test",
                'name'          =>  "test",
                'caption'       =>  "test",
                'description'   =>  "test",
                'link'          =>  "myurl",
                'picture'       =>  "mypictureurl/test.jpg",
            );
            try{
                $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $params );
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo "<pre>";var_dump($e); echo "</pre>";echo "<hr>";
                echo "<pre>";var_dump($post_url);echo "</pre>";
            }
```

This actually works fine and it post the image before, but now with the test.jpg for some reason it doesn't display in a group. I optimized the image, I change it from png to jpg or jpeg, but still no image. What should I do ? thx

Comment: any idea ? why my image is not posted ?

Comment: I would recommend to use Facebook PHP SDK v.4. Many things have changed in the API and even more after the migration to Graph API V2.